# GitHub auto-assign reviewer for merge request

Tags: github

We are using GitHub Enterprise.

Is it possible to auto assign reviewers to a merge request in GitHub? I have explored every setting and tried a lot of things but when the merge request is created, merge request creator has to manually assign the reviewer(s).

I would like to specify a team or person(s) to be auto assigned as reviewer(s) somewhere in the settings so that whenever a merge request is created, that team or person(s) are automatically assigned as reviewer(s) for the merge request.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) and require a code owner review in the branch protection settings?

Comment: code owners file can be changed by someone and I am trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: If you require PR reviews and designate code owners for CODEOWNERS, you could prevent somebody from merging a change. Any other automated method I can think  of would use Actions, which are also just files that can be modified.